# How to use lagom in scala3

Tags: scala, sbt, lagom, scala-3

I want to compile my lagom project in Scala 3.
Follow this documentation [scala3 documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/tutorial-sbt.html), when prepare the dependencies, I change my build.sbt:

```
    lazy val `service-api` = (project in file("service-api"))
      .settings(
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          lagomScaladslApi
        ).map(_.cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13))
      )
```

but lagom API depends other projects can't found.

error info:

```
[error] (service-api / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.lightbend.lagom:lagom-scaladsl-server_3:1.6.4
[error]   Not found
```

Comment: Lagom is not yet compatible with Scala 3 AFAIK (Play isn't yet neither). And this is not the kind of projects that you can use in 2.13 mode as it pulls many stuff including macros which are not compatible with Scala 3 right away.